# In React, how can I use children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep getting this error saying children are not supported in React.

```
return (
 8 |         <Route>
 9 |             {...rest}
   |             ^^^^^^^^^
10 |             render={props => {
11 |                 return currentUser ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect > to="/login" />
```

This is the code

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom"
import { useAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext"

function PrivateRoute( { component: Component, ...rest }) {
    const { currentUser } = useAuth()
    return (
        <Route>
            {...rest}
            render={props => {
                return currentUser ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />

            }}
        </Route>
    )
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the entire error message

Answer (score 0):

You are including the props and the render property as a child component instead of a property of the Route component.

Try the below:

```
<Route
   {...rest}
   render={props => {
      return currentUser ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
}} />
```

Comment: Awesome, do you mind marking this as the correct answer? @mcolumbusua21

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to manually add the children prop into your React functional component?

There is no need to do that, React automatically sends children as a prop, as can be seen [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html).

Here is how you could rewrite your functional component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom"
import { useAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext"

interface PrivateRouteProps {
    component: Component;
    children: React.ReactNode;
}

const PrivateRoute = (props: PrivateRouteProps) => {
    const { currentUser } = useAuth()
    return (
        <Route>
            {...props.children}
            render={props => {
                return currentUser ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />

            }}
        </Route>
    )
}
```

If you have any questions about this code, feel free to just leave a comment below.